# How to filter out from a list of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code.

```
const a="144466,122332";
```

At first I am converting string of numbers into array of integers.

```
const b= a.split(',').map(i=>parseInt(i,10));

const c=[{id:144466,name:'abc'},
         {id:122332,name:'efg'},
         {id:13366,name:'xyz'}]
```

Now I am applying filter.

```
c.filter(c.id===b).map(item=><p>{item.name}</p>)
```

But I am not getting the result.

Comment: whats your expected result?

Comment: c.filter(d=> d.id===b).map(item=><p>{item.name}</p>)

Comment: If I got your intention right, the correct code would be `c.filter(c => b.indexOf(c.id) > -1).map(item => <p>{item.name}</p>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use includes() method:

```js
let result = c.filter(x => b.includes(x.id)).map(item=><p>{item.name}</p>)
```